# MongoDB query to fetch records created 'n' days ago

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, codeigniter

I have a MySQL query which I use run to fetch records created 27 days ago.

```
SELECT *
FROM appointments
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(created_dt, '%m/%d/%Y') = DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(SYSDATE(), INTERVAL 27 DAY), '%m/%d/%Y')
```

How do I do this in MongoDB?

I am using codeigniter, so +1 for a mongo_db query.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you mean with "created 'n' days ago"

You can choose between one of the [Comparison Query Operators](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query-comparison/)

So if you want all records created exact ([$eq](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/#op._S_eq)) n days ago it would look something like this.

```
db.appointments.find({"created_dt" : { $eq : new ISODate("2016-05-04T12:00:00Z") }});
```

And you could calculate the Date from the current Date.

Note:

I don't know if you can use `$eq` and just pass a day and get all records equal to that day. It could work but you would need to try this first.

If it doesn't work you can make a workaround like this

```
db.appointments.find({"created_dt" : { $gte : today, $lt : nextDay}});
```

where `today` is `today at 00:00:00` and `nextDay` is `nextDay at 00:00:00` (note the `$lt` instead of `$lte`)